# How to implement OAuth2 provider and consumer in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have been doing a bit of searching around on oauth2 and think it may be a good fit for some WCF rest services I am building out that will be consumed by some WPF apps and MVC web apps. The idea would be that the user is initially asked to login with their username / password and receives an access token which gives them access to the aforementioned resource(s).

Searching around here on SO I have not found much information on oauth2 except for a few consumer related questions to facebook etc.

I'm wondering if anybody can provide some tips on implementing oauth2 (or knows of any good resources). I am interested in both the provider (authenticating and issuing access tokens) as well as the client/consumer end.

**.NET OAuth2 Libraries**

The only OAuth2 library I found is from dotnetopenauth which also seems to be heavily into openid. At this stage I'd rather a library that is a little lighter and just emcompasses oauth2

Are there any other oauth2 libraries available yet?

Comment: Provider libraries are answer by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries/

Answer (score 2):

There's [OAuth .NET](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/)

Comment: Hi Alex. From what I can tell that OAuth library is for oauth1x. Looking at their roadmap they are planning oauth 2 for their next major release.